# Bulk Actions on Rails Restful Resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources, rest

I am trying to implement a bulk update feature in a Rails app, the model I want to update is a restful resource. I need to display a table where each row is a single resource and has a check box. The user can check as many boxes as they like and then chose an action to perform on all of the selected resources, eg delete, change status etc.

Does anyone have a an idea of how best this fits into the rails restful way of doing things?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ryan Bates has a couple of Railscasts covering this:

[Update through checkboxes](http://railscasts.com/episodes/52-update-through-checkboxes)

[Edit Multiple](http://railscasts.com/episodes/165-edit-multiple)

Comment: Answers should not be just links

Comment: Yes, sadly the reason is manifest here as Railscasts is no longer up.